# Swift - Inconsistent timing of crash in reloadData? (after deleting data element without corresponding deleteRowsAtIndexPaths)

Tags: ios, swift, crash, reloaddata

This started out as a request for help figuring out why I was having a crash in reloadData() when swipe-deleting items from a practice "to-do" app, but as I was carefully documenting what I knew and had tried I figured out that the issue was. Isn't that always the way? :)

The crash occurred in reloadData() when I removed an element from the data array but had omitted the call to

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

I would get a crash on the second *or subsequent* deletion. I get why I was getting a crash; if I grok correctly, since tableView:numberOfRowsInSection returned the number of elements in the data array I need to explicitly remove the corresponding row with tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths to keep things in sync.

What's not clear to me is why sometimes the crash only occurred on the third or fourth (I don't think I saw it later than that) deletion. If I changed the code by, e.g., adding in some println() tracing around the call to reloadData(), the crash would occur after different numbers of deletions. It would (I think) be consistent for any specific code sequence, but I can't see why println() would interact this way.

Is there something variable that could be allowing it to "limp past" the inconsistency a few times, or something?

I learned a lot figuring out the issue myself, and I feel like I'm starting to get a deeper understanding but still "through a glass, darkly". Maybe understanding the timing of this crash will make the glass a little more transparent. :)

Thanks!

Code below:

```
import UIKit
var toDoList = [ToDoItem]()

func saveToDoList() {
    let toDoListData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(toDoList)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(toDoListData, forKey: "toDoList")
    }

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var toDoListTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoList") != nil {
            let toDoListData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("toDoList") as NSData
            toDoList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(toDoListData) as [ToDoItem]
            }
        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return toDoList.count
        }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "toDoListItem")

        cell.textLabel?.text = toDoList[indexPath.row].name

        if toDoList[indexPath.row].completed {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            }
        else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            }

        return cell
        }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        toDoListTable.reloadData()
        }

    func tableView(
            tableView: UITableView,
            commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,
            forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath
            ) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

            toDoList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

            saveToDoList()

            }
        tableView.reloadData()

        }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

        var toDoItem = toDoList[indexPath.row]
        toDoItem.completed = !toDoItem.completed

        tableView.reloadData()
        }

}
```

Comment: I am currently experiencing this same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote above. - I resolved the problem by adding the call to deleteRowsAtIndexPaths appropriately.